# Xcode 6 device console size?

Tags: xcode

The device console in Xcode 6 seems to be about 12 lines long, and does not appear to be resizable.  This makes it very hard to see the log output from the device, and the iPhone Configuration Utility no longer seems to work, at least not with iOS 8 devices.

Any ideas on how to resize the log output pane, or otherwise see more of the live logs?

Comment: It's definitely resizable, drag the top border.

Comment: @JackWu - I think I've tried to drag on every pixel of that top border and failed.  What's the secret?  (I see a hide/show arrow and a scroll bar, no other controls.)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Move the mouse slowly upward from the divider line from the console area and the top area - about 12 pixels higher even than the arrow that expands/contracts the screen (and about 40 pixels above the line), the cursor will turn into a resizing handle you can use to drag and move the dividing line.

There's no static visual indicator otherwise, it's quite far from the line.

Note this is for the console in Devices, not the debugging console where it's lots easier to figure out how to resize the window top.

Comment: Even with your instructions (which are quite good!), it still took me another 5 attempts before I found it.  :)

Comment: It's pretty invisible!  Glad you found it though.

Comment: Damn, could Apple have made it any more cryptic?!?  Thanks though, at least it is resizable!

Comment: damn, that's hard to find. For me, initially I only found it towards the right hand side of the window. But then I noticed you can "reveal" where the line is, with a two finger scroll of the top-half (Device info & Installed Apps)

Comment: It looks like the line also appears if you shrink the window as small as you can. It looks like the line is only visible if the console log butts up against the bottom of the installed apps list.

Comment: Wow, it's only 20 pixels off, but it's there if you move slow enough.

Comment: Thanks. It was driving me crazy. Resizing the window (to be smaller) helps.

Answer (score 23):

Even with Kendall's instructions it can still be tricky to find the sweet spot, so here is an screenshot to make it easier:

[image: the invisible resizing handle]

Comment: Very nice, I applaud the effort to make the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I use iPhone Configuration Utility instead

Comment: Is there a new version of the iPhone Config utility available?  There version I have, v3.5, seems to be the latest version I can find on Apple's website, and this does not support iOS 8 devices.